# How to combine measures with different dimensionality into single select statement using MDX & Analysis Services (SSAS)?

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

I would like to add a measure that has different dimensionality to the same SELECT mdx statement. In general, most of my measures are linked to [Customer Creation Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Month Name]. 
However, Anonymous customers do not have the link to customer creation date; therefore, I have to link anonymous to Enquiry Creation Date. How to combine two measures into single select query.

```
> WITH  MEMBER [Measures].[Allow Contact] as
            ([Measures].[# CRM Customers],[Customer].[Customer Allow Contact].&[Yes],[Customer].[Customer Status].&[Active] )

        MEMBER [Measures].[Total Identified Customers] AS
            ([Measures].[# CRM Customers],[Customer].[Customer Status].&[Active] )

        MEMBER [Measures].[Anonymous Customers] AS
            ([Measures].[# Unique Distinct Customers on Contact],[Enquiry].[Anonymous].&[Yes]) 



SELECT NON EMPTY {  Measures].[Allow Contact], 
                    [Measures].[Total Identified Customers]
                    //,[Measures].[Anonymous Customers]

                 } ON COLUMNS
       ,NON EMPTY ([Customer Creation Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Month Name]
       //,[Enquiry Creation Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Month Name] //How to add different dimensionality  

       ) ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

Comment: Have you created the dimension [Enquiry Creation Date], which would need to have a regular relationship to your calendar dimension in your cube structure?

Comment: Yes, I have created regular relationship between calendar dimension & fact table. The problem is that I want to use different calendar dimension for Anonymous customers.

Comment: You can create 2 other measures, having the counts of new customers based on creation date, and also the inquiry count. Take a look at this link which elaborates scenarios where you have 2 date dimensions - http://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2009/12/16/date-dimension-in-analysis-services-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

If both time dimensions have the same structure (which should obviously be the case if they are implemented as role playing dimensions on the same dimension object), you can use the [`LinkMember` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146058.aspx) in the definition of `[Measures].[Anonymous Customers]` to use the `[Customer Creation Date].[Date Hierarchy]` in the rows, but use these dates as the `[Enquiry Creation Date].[Date Hierarchy]` in the measure calculation:

```
WITH  MEMBER [Measures].[Allow Contact] as
            ([Measures].[# CRM Customers],[Customer].[Customer Allow Contact].&[Yes],[Customer].[Customer Status].&[Active] )

        MEMBER [Measures].[Total Identified Customers] AS
            ([Measures].[# CRM Customers],[Customer].[Customer Status].&[Active] )

        MEMBER [Measures].[Anonymous Customers] AS
            ([Measures].[# Unique Distinct Customers on Contact],[Enquiry].[Anonymous].&[Yes], 
             LinkMember([Customer Creation Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember, [Enquiry Creation Date].[Date Hierarchy]) 

SELECT NON EMPTY {  Measures].[Allow Contact], 
                    [Measures].[Total Identified Customers]
                   ,[Measures].[Anonymous Customers]
                 } ON COLUMNS
       ,NON EMPTY ([Customer Creation Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Month Name]
       ) ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

Comment: Many thanks Frank. The solution almost works. The dimensions have the same structure; however, calculation is correct for the first month only. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Depending on how you modeled your cube, it may help to add the *all* member of the `[Customer Creation Date].[Date Hierarchy]` hierarchy to the tuple for the `[Anonymous Customers]` measure, i. e. use something like `([Measures].[# Unique Distinct Customers on Contact],[Enquiry].[Anonymous].&[Yes], LinkMember([Customer Creation Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember, [Enquiry Creation Date].[Date Hierarchy], [Customer Creation Date].[Date Hierarchy].[All]) `